# Custom SVG directive inside button Component

Tags: angular, svg, ionic2

I created a simple `Directive` that can be added to an `<i>` tag :

```
<i svg-icon="menu"></i>
```

It takes the name of the `SVG` file (in the exemple: `menu.svg`). Wherever I use it, it's works perfectly, the icon is correctly shown, except inside a `<button>` `Component` :

```
<button ion-button menuToggle>
    <i svg-icon="menu"></i>
</button>
```

In this context, the icon is not displayed.

Here is the content the **`SvgIconDirective`** :

```
import ...

@Directive({
    selector: '[svg-icon]'
})
export class SvgIconDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input('svg-icon') name: string;
    @Input() class: string;

    constructor(
        private el: ElementRef,
        private http: Http
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.http.get(`assets/icon/ic_${this.name}.svg`).map(response => response.text()).subscribe(data => {
            let element = $(this.el.nativeElement);

            const id = element.attr('id');
            const className = element.attr('class');

            let newElement = $('<div />').html(data).find('svg');

            if (typeof id !== 'undefined') {
                newElement.attr('id', id);
            }
            if (typeof className !== 'undefined') {
                newElement.addClass(className);
            }

            $(this.el.nativeElement).replaceWith(newElement);
        });
    }
}
```

And the `DOM` render inside `<button>` tag :

```
<button ion-button="" menutoggle="" class="disable-hover bar-buttons bar-buttons-md bar-button bar-button-md bar-button-default bar-button-default-md bar-button-menutoggle bar-button-menutoggle-md" ng-reflect-menu-toggle="" style="transition: none;">
    <span class="button-inner">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Calque_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 52.4 44.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 52.4 44.1;" xml:space="preserve">
            <style type="text/css">
                .ic_menu .st0{fill:#444444;}
            </style>
            <g class="ic_menu">
                <g transform="translate(312, 312)">
                    <path class="st0" d="M-259.6-312H-312v6.4h52.4V-312z"/>
                </g>
                <g transform="translate(312, 312)">
                    <path class="st0" d="M-259.6-293.1H-312v6.4h52.4V-293.1z"/>
                </g>
                <g transform="translate(312, 312)">
                    <path class="st0" d="M-259.6-274.3H-312v6.4h52.4V-274.3z"/>
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </span>
    <div class="button-effect">
    </div>
</button>
```

Comment: What if you remove all directives from button ? Is it work ?

Comment: By removing `ion-button` and `menuToggle` ? Still the same.

Comment: What does your DOM look like inside the button? Did you check if your directive gets instantiated in this case?

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh the directive is correctly instantiated, I edited my post with the directive DOM render inside <button> tag.

Comment: Ok, that's something at least. I suggest you to check all the width / height of the elements. Your SVG is wrapped into span which will have 0x0 dimensions if display property is not overridden. It has something to do with calculating SVG dimensions.. Maybe repaint / reflow. If I were on your place I'd play with setting width / height to wrapper explicitly, overflow property, etc. I cannot test your code in the real life, cannot tell more from what you've posted.

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh Thanks for theses informations! it was indeed a problem linked to the `svg` wrapped into `span` and others tags. I found a solution for my issue that I'll post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by simply replacing the `<button ion-button ...></button>` with a `div` :

```
<div class="CustomClass" menuToggle>
    <i svg-icon="menu"></i>
</div>
```